# Failed to install-write all apks Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, apk

I can only run my Android Studio app on a physical device, but when I try to run my app on Android Emulator, I get this error:

```
'Installation failed.Failed to install-write all apks'
```

UPDATE: I run my app on the emulator with the Android version 7.0 and it was ok

Comment: could you tell the model of both physical device and avd?

Comment: Avd is NEXUS-S API 30 and the physical device is Huawei

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but followed the steps below and my problem was solved.

Disable Instant Run
(MAC: Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck : Enable Instant Run)
(Windows: File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck : Enable Instant Run)